# Is it possible to adjust the backlight of a DELL U2414H monitor connected via HDMI?

Tags: hdmi

I have a magic mirror I'm building that has a RPI at it's heart but even with the screen blanked at night, I can see the backlight glowing.

Is there any way to adjust backlight brightness via the HDMI connection or am I going to have to modify the monitor's hardware? Seems like it ought to be possible via software.

Comment: perhaps HDMI-CEC may work with the monitor